# Insert Data into MySQL Database Using Radio Button in PHP doesnt work properly undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

these are my forms:

```
<Form name ="formbehuizing" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing1'>Sharkoon VS3-S red </br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing2'>Sharkoon VS3-S blue </br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing3'>Sharkoon VS3-S green </br>

        </FORM>

<Form name ="formvoeding" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= 'voeding1'>Cooler Master G600 EU</br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= 'voeding2'>Cooler Master B700 </br>


        </FORM>`<Form name ="formprocessor" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor1'>Intel&reg; Core&trade; i3 4130 3,4 GHz</br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor2'>Intel&reg; Core&trade; i5 4670K 3.40 Ghz </br>
        <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor3'>Intel&reg; Core&trade; i7 4770K 3.5 GHz </br>

        </FORM>`
```

this is the radiobutton.php file

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
if(login_check($mysqli) == true) {

$behuizing= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['behuizing']);
$voeding= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['voeding']);
$processor = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['processor']);

$sql="INSERT INTO dario_bestelling (behuizing, voeding, processor)
VALUES ('$behuizing', '$voeding', '$processor')";

if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($mysqli);
} else { 
        echo 'You are not authorized to access this page, please login.';
}
?>
```

i keep getting the undefined index notice,the auto increment works but the info that normally is added by the radiobuttons isnt added in my database.

Comment: The reason for this is that you have 3 forms all using the same action file. Use one form with all your radio buttons inside it `<form>all radio buttons</form>`

Comment: the thing is that i need it to be in 1 file because it is an order from a webshop. that needs to be in 1 record of the database

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "one record"?

Comment: it needs to be in 1 row of my DB it is a webshop to assemble your own computer. and each form is a part like motherboard then there are 3 options to choose between. then the next form is for a processor and again three options to choose between.

Comment: So why don't you just setup different columns instead? Show me an example of what you want it to look like then.

Comment: is it ok that i give you a link to the web page? so you can see it yourself

Comment: Sure I'll have a look at it. In the meantime, see the answer that's been given below.

Comment: http://www.depest.be/DarioS/gip/pp3.php here you go :)

Comment: You don't need the additional form tags, just one. You accepted the answer that I've already outlined in my comments.

Comment: I don't know why you accepted an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that mistake. I should have been more careful. Is it common practice on Stack Overflow to actually create a test environment and test one's code before submitting an answer? I kind of assumed that the code snippets would not be used verbatim, but as a starting point.

Comment: That wasn't a verbatim, the conditional statement you originally wrote was missing a few brackets. @Stevish Your code now checks out and the OP should be well on his/her way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using separate forms for each set of radio buttons, and none of them have a submit button. Only the inputs within the form that is being submitted will be passed to the server. So `$_POST['behuizing']`, `$_POST['voeding']`, and  `$_POST['processor']` are not defined, giving you that error. Your form should look like this:

```
<Form name ="formbehuizing" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing1' />Sharkoon VS3-S red <br />
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing2' />Sharkoon VS3-S blue <br />
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='behuizing' value= 'behuizing3' />Sharkoon VS3-S green <br /><br />

    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= 'voeding1' />Cooler Master G600 EU<br />
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='voeding' value= 'voeding2' />Cooler Master B700 <br /><br />

    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor1' />Intel&reg; Core&trade; i3 4130 3,4 GHz<br />
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor2' />Intel&reg; Core&trade; i5 4670K 3.40 Ghz <br />
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='processor' value= 'processor3' />Intel&reg; Core&trade; i7 4770K 3.5 GHz <br />

    <Input type = 'submit' Name ='submit' value= 'Submit' ><br />

</FORM>
```

Also, to avoid the error in the event someone doesn't check any of the buttons on a particular set (like processor), you can use `isset()` like this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['behuizing'] ) && isset( $_POST['voeding'] ) && isset( $_POST['processor'] ) ) {
    $behuizing = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['behuizing']);
    $voeding = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['voeding']);
    $processor = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['processor']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO dario_bestelling (behuizing, voeding, processor) 
        VALUES ('$behuizing', '$voeding', '$processor')";

    if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
} else {
    echo "You didn't choose all the options! No record was added. Please choose one option from each category";
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer based on the OP's need to have all three variables set

Comment: thank you! the only thing is that im putting information between the different groups of radiobuttons and also images. is there a way to do that with this code to?

Comment: Yes, you can put non-form elements like pictures and text inside a form. Just pretend the form is a `<div>`.

Comment: ok thank you!! if i could give you a vote up i would do it :D

Comment: what do you mean with OP's?

Comment: im getting an error when i use this code
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting ',' or ')' in"

Comment: Oops, sorry. I missed my closing parentheses in the isset() functions. I've updated my answer

Comment: OP = original poster  = you. From what you explained in a comment, a user would need to make a selection from all three radio button sets. The PHP now requires that